# How to load local images to shiny app for image analysis with EBImage

Tags: image-processing, shiny

I would like to create a shiny dashboard app for image analysis using EBImage. My doubt is how to load a local image to the app using EBImage package for posterior analysis.

In internet I see how to load images from EBImage-package's system file like this example:

```
library(shiny)
library(EBImage)
library(displayWidget)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Display widget demo"),

  # Sidebar with a select input for the image
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("image", "Sample image:", list.files(system.file("images", package="EBImage")))
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Static display", plotOutput("display")),
        tabPanel("Interactive widget", displayWidgetOutput("widget"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  img <- reactive({
    f = system.file("images", input$image, package="EBImage")
    x = readImage(f)
  })

  output$widget <- renderDisplayWidget({
    displayWidget(img())
  })

  output$display <- renderPlot({
    display(img(), method="raster", all=TRUE)
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know how to load local data using this:

```
DataXLSX <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$fileXLSX

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    loadXLSX <- read.xlsx(inFile$datapath)
    loadXLSX    
  })
```

But I cannot do the same with readImage(). Some help? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable file upload in your app, you need to replace the `selectInput("image", ...)` widget for picking an image from a predefined list of sample files by a `fileInput` control, and use its value in the reactive expression `img` to access the local copy of the uploaded file. You will also need to guard the execution of the expressions inside `renderDisplayWidget` and `renderPlot` by a call to `req(img())` in order to defer image display until an image file is selected and loaded. See below for a complete working example. 
Please note that the functionality provided by the R package [displayWidget](https://github.com/aoles/displayWidget) has been integrated into [*EBImage* devel](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/EBImage.html) branch, so loading *displayWidget* is obsolete as of *EBImage* version 4.19.3.

```
library("shiny")
library("EBImage")# >= 4.19.3

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Image display"),

  # Sidebar with a select input for the image
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("image", "Select image")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Static raster", plotOutput("raster")),
        tabPanel("Interactive browser", displayOutput("widget"))
      )
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  img <- reactive({
    f <- input$image
    if (is.null(f))
      return(NULL)        
    readImage(f$datapath)
  })

  output$widget <- renderDisplay({
    req(img())
    display(img())
  })

  output$raster <- renderPlot({
    req(img())
    plot(img(), all=TRUE)
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Last night I could load local images doing the same but without req() function. Thanks again